# ¿Cómo autenticarse desde una pagina web cliente usando API externo en laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel-8, auth, adminlte, middleware

estoy aprendiendo Laravel, pero tengo un problema al loguearme ya que para el login solo envió el usuario y la contraseña, ya la **API me retorno el token**. Pero no se como guardarlo los datos retornados para que verifica que ya se encuentra autenticado. Además, estoy usando el **template de AdminLTE** y necesito que se pueda mostrar la opción de logout pero para es necesario que Existe el **Auth::user**.
Espero haberme explicado lo suficiente como para dar a conocer mi inconveniente.

Adjunto mi código petición desde el lado cliente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginUsuarioRequest;
use App\Models\Configuracion;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    return view('adminlte::auth.login');
  }
  public function login(LoginUsuarioRequest $request)
  {
    $response = Configuracion::where('ruc', $request->input('ruc'))->get();
    $isExist = false;
    foreach ($response as $value) {
      if($value->estado == 1) {
        $isExist = true;
      }
    }
    if ($isExist) {
      try {
        $client = new Client();
        $params = array(
          'email' => $request->input('email'),
          'password' => $request->input('password')
        );
        $headers = [
          'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ];
        $url = 'http://apirest.rca/api/iniciarsesion';
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
          'form_params' => $params,
          'headers' => $headers,
          'verify'  => false,
        ]);
        $clientes = json_decode($response->getBody());
        echo json_encode($clientes);

      } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        echo $th->getMessage();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Respuesta del API:

```
{
  "res": true,
  "token": "1|kwRbV555vRSOzTvAtZzFvSLMMbcMrAlBDESvlWLYh8jNEr8xJf",
  "usuario": {
    "nid_usuario": 1,
    "txt_nombre": "Demo",
    "txt_apellido": "Usuario 1",
    "txt_email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "txt_password": "$2y$10$QC6tZzknSmRlBYnrE3rNne8WNSZ3rHeRLSzTmDozTDaFeJTvI5GEO",
    "flg_activo": 0
  }
}
```

Para que se muestre la opción de logout es necesario que este autenticado:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es la siguiente: "Pero no se como guardarlo los datos retornados para que verifica que ya se encuentra autenticado".

Para guardar los datos en el Front lo más usado es guardarlo en `LocalStorage` de tu navegador.

Es decir en tu método o función de JavaScript donde recibes el `Response` del Backend, en una variable guardas el `Response` y posteriormente el `token` en el `LocalStorage`. En tu Front harías algo similar a:

```
localStorage['token'] = response.token
```

La información se estaría guardando en el navegador del usuario y para verificar que se almacenó correctamente podrías activar el `devtools`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando desees acceder a ese dato ya que necesitaras enviarlo en cada petición o `Request` que esté protegida por `JWT` lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```
const token  = localStorage['token']
```

Ya solo queda agregar `token` en el arreglo u objeto donde envías el `Request` , el Backend validará que el token sea el correcto y te dará acceso.